# Cannot save stdin input into a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to save some input from stdin as a list, so that I could do some manipulation on it

I have this very simple code, where I'm just trying to save input lines in a list.

```
list=[]
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    list.append(line)

print(list)
```

When I run this file, I copy this input data in the console:

```
3
2
2 2 4 5 7
```

But when I do this, nothing happens. It's like the program is just at a standstill. How do I save the input to a list that I can work with?

Comment: You probably need to tell it that the input has reached end of file. In Linux you would press ctrl-D. In Windows I think it might be ctrl-Z but I'm not sure (don't really use Windows).

Comment: Did you put a EOF?

Comment: when i input the input?

Comment: `Ctrl-Z` is correct for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine.

If you run it from an IDE, you may need to find out what is the keystroke for an EOF marker. For example, in PyCharm it's Ctrl+D like in Linux, while on a Windows command prompt it's Ctrl+Z.

So, run `python script.py` from the command line, enter the text and enter Ctrl+Z. Or run the script from your IDE and enter the text followed by Ctrl+D.

Alternatively, put your text in a text file and run `python script.py < text.txt`